# If it is possible to show the Gmail, HotMail,Yahoo.. etc in Salesforce?

Tags: gmail, salesforce, mule, mule-studio, salesforce-service-cloud

How to show the Gmail, Hot Mail,Yahoo.. etc in salesforce.Once open my account in salesforce the gmail,hotmail and yahoo mail details should show in the same account. if it is possible means how can i do using custom object. What are the possible ways for do this concept in salesforce. otherwise can i use any integration tool for this concept like MULE STUDIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce can integrate with Gmail and Outlook, see their [FAQ](http://www.salesforce.com/smallbusinesscenter/faq/email.jsp) to review if this feature suits your needs. If you need other features or email providers, you can use Mule to connect to your email and Salesforce. There are Mule connector available for [Gmail](http://mulesoft.github.io/google-connectors-suite/gmail-connector/mule/gmail-config-with-oauth.html), [email](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Email+Transport+Reference), and [Salesforce](http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/salesforce-cloud-connector).

Comment: We can integrate yahoo or any mail with SFDC using Mulestudio? if it is possible means which component can i use.

Comment: You can use the Mule email connector to access any Pop3 or IMAP email server, such as Yahoo.